# libgdx: Is there a way to "fast-forward" particle effects?

Tags: libgdx, particles

I've worked with Game Maker previously to using libgdx, and one thing you could do is skip ahead in a particle's animation.  For instance, if you have a snow particle effect, when you enter a room the snow particles would only just begin falling.  But if you used the part_system_update() method repeatedly upon entering the room, you could "fast-forward" the effect, making it appear as if the snow had been falling before you entered the room.  Is there a way to achieve that same result in libgdx?

Comment: Could you refer me a link how to create a snow based particle system for android, Please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can update it when is created using the desired big float.

[ParticleEffect#update](http://libgdx.l33tlabs.org/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/ParticleEffect.html#update%28float%29)

```
float startp = 0.5F; //for example
particleEffect.update(startp);
```